# We may all be paranoid - but for real reasons, not [advanced-delusionary-schizophrenia]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

As a (not bad) joke, the following tags were added to the now deleted question at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172515/traffic-being-routed-to-uk-ministry-of-defense

[advanced-delusionary-schizophrenia](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-delusionary-schizophrenia)
[time-travel](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel)
[earth-in-the-middle-attacks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/earth-in-the-middle-attacks)

As truly useful as the first two might be for some of the lesser of questions to cross this site, they're still unfortunately off topic. I don't really know what an earth in the middle attack is, google isn't being helpful - but I suspect it also doesn't belong.

Comment: AFAIK, tags with zero tagged questions are removed automatically after some time. So I don't think there is any action required.

Comment: As Arminius points out, that was apparently done as a joke. Two of the tags have no questions associated with them, so will be automagically removed soon.

Comment: [time-travel] does in fact have a question and seems to be reasonably on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

No need to worry, the garbage collector eats up all tags with zero questions once a day or so. So no harm is done.

Two of the tags have already been automatically deleted. The third, [time-travel](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) is still around but for a legitimate reason. It has gotten a tag excerpt with a good on topic usage guide, and an on topic question is tagged with it:

> This tag relates to the creation of network logs and similar information to enable "time travel" in an envrionment to understand it's state at a given point in time.